# Show notification automatically

Tags: android

I am using this code to show a notification on my smartwatch:

```
 Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Message")
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon))
                .build();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

How can I show it automatically on my smartwatch screen when it is created? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**it called Heads-up notifications**

per developer site : you can use it if:

> The user's activity is in fullscreen mode (the app uses
>   fullScreenIntent).
>
> The notification has high priority and uses ringtones or vibrations on
>   devices running Android 7.1 (API level 25) and lower.
>
> The notification channel has high importance on devices running
>   Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher.

so what you need to do is adding this :

`builder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);`

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle("Message")
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon));

        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(UPDATE_NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
```